# Update database using onblur

Tags: php, ajax

Javascript update

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('select').on('change',function(){
  var id  = $(this).closest('tr').find('#idbase').val();
  var price  = $(this).closest('tr').find('#cost').val();
  var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();
  var sum = price * quantity;
  var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('#total_qty').text(sum);

$.ajax({ // added {
url: "../Database/Query/EditOrder.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
    'id': id,
    'Quantity': quantity
},
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
}); // added }

});
});
```

EditOrder.php code

```
 <?php
require("../../Connection/Connect.php");

// php delete data in mysql database using PDO
if(isset($_POST['EditProduct']))
{
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}

 // get id to delete


$id = $_POST['id'];
$Quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$Subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];



$sql = "UPDATE cart SET Quantity = :quantity WHERE id = :idbase";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(":quantity"=>$Quantity, ":idbase"=>$id));

if($result){
header("Location: ../Public/Cart.php");
} else {
echo 'error';
}

}
?>
```

I'm trying to update the database using onblur of select and getting the value of quantity and sum to be saved in database, But my database is still not updating am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

js code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){$('select').on('change',function(){
  var id  = $(this).closest('tr').find('#idbase').val();
  var price  = $(this).closest('tr').find('#cost').val();
  var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();
  var sum = price * quantity;
  var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('#total_qty').text(sum);

$.ajax({ // added {
url: "../Database/Query/EditOrder.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
    'id': id,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'subtotal' : sum
},
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
}); // added }

});
});
```

php code

```
<?php
require("../../Connection/Connect.php"); // if this connect.php file contains your database connection then i guess you don't need to connect the data base again 
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['subtotal']))
{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$Quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$Subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$sql = "UPDATE cart SET Quantity = :quantity WHERE id = :idbase";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(":quantity"=>$Quantity, ":idbase"=>$id));
if($result){
echo "updated";
} else {
echo 'error';
}

}
}
    ?>
```

Comment: The database is currently updating but it says the undefined index for the quantity and subtotal

Comment: You had little mistake in both js and php code . i have modified the code fully . now i think its gonna work